# How to use Pyspark to merge multilple columns into two columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame like this:

```
Date,        product_a,    product_b,   product_c
2021-01-01,   True ,      True,         False
2021-01-02,   False,      True,         False
```

The expected format is:

```
Date,        product,    status
2021-01-01,   a,         True
2021-01-01,   b,         True
2021-01-01,   c,         False
2021-01-02,   a,         False
2021-01-02,   a,         True
2021-01-02,   a,         False
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a small `dataframe` and `join` it with your data then generate the `status` column based on the `product_x` values and the new column created by `join`

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    frame_for_join=spark.createDataFrame([('a',),('b',),('c',)],["product"])
    result=spark_df.join(frame_for_join,how="cross").withColumn("status",
       ((col("product_a")==True) & (col("product")=='a')) |  
       ((col("product_b")==True) & (col("product")=='b')) |
       ((col("product_c")==True) & (col("product")=='c'))).
       select("Date","product","status")
```

Answer (score 0):

Find another way which works by spark sql:

'''
SELECT * FROM tb01
UNPIVOT (
status FOR product IN (product_a, product_b, product_c)
);
'''